# LoadRunner web service testing and SAML token

Tags: soapui, saml, loadrunner

I want to loadtest a web service by creating a SOAP request in SoapUI and pasting it into a regular LoadRunner web virtual user within a web_custom_request(). This should be straight forward and is described i.e. here:
http://www.jds.net.au/tech-tips/web-services-with-a-web-vuser/

The problem arises when the web service is behind Security and requires a SAML token to accept the request. I have managed to generate this SAML token in SoapUI with some customization from the developers in my project, and the test works there (for the duration of the SAML token, that is)

My rationale is then that I can paste this soap request with the SAML token into LoadRunner and it should work. However this SAML token would expire and then, my test will stop working.

Is there a way to generate SAML assertions/wsse header in LoadRunner?

In general how does LoadRunner cope with SAML tokens?

Comment: If you can't get it to work in LoadRunner, it's pretty much guaranteed to work in LoadUI, since it uses the SoapUI engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is providing the token then you must include a separate call for a valid token string before your service call in the the LoadRunner script and correlate the token string.

I have taken the same approach to testing web services in LR and what sometimes helps is instead of starting with a blank script using LR to record SOAPUI making the service call. Early calls to the server for things like session IDs and tokens will then get captured for you. Doesn't always work, depends on your service and server setup, but it has been helpful in the past.

Comment: Ok, in general, what kind of support does LoadRunner have to cope with saml tokens?